# How to prevent boot manager missing after cloning a win764 image using Ghost 2003?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot-manager, ghost-image

I am running ghost 2003 command -fdsp, but once we have cloned the image and restored it onto exactly the same make and model machine, we are force to run win7 setup and run a repair which fixes the boot menu, I want to prevent this requirement to fix the problem, any suggestions besides the obvious of using Windows AIK tools, new versions of ghost/clonzilla.

I want to prevent the problem in the first place, it's 1 partition only, on a levano workstation m82 with UEFI and a 100mb system reserved partition.

Windows Boot Manager screen and states:

> Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might
>   be the cause. To fix the problem:
>
> 1.Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer.
>   2.Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
>   3.Click "Repair you computer."    If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for
>   assistance.
>
> Status: 0xc000000e

Comment: Sometimes Windows creates 2 partitions so I think you need to copy that 100MB system reserved partition too.

Comment: the ghost image contains the 100mb partition - after checking it's content it contains system volume info, boot manager and bcd settings.

Comment: I hate to imply a "newer version" answer -- but does Ghost 2003 even know what UEFI is?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the restored partition ACTIVE by using DISKPART. At a command prompt:

```
DISKPART
LIST DISK  
SELECT DISK x (where x is the physical boot disk)  
LIST PARTITION  
SELECT PARTITION x (where x is the partition where Windows resides)  
ACTIVE  
EXIT  
EXIT
```

Then reboot.

You may encounter the dreaded `BOOTMGR is missing` error after rebooting. You will then need to use the Windows 7 installation DVD and allow it to repair or manually by entering `BOOTREC /FIXMBR` and `BOOTREC /FIXBOOT`.